# sms handling originatingaddress

Tags: android, sms

sir, can you teach me a way to use the sender variable in other classes. i've tried other ways but it just displays null value. thanks

```
 String sender;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
    Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); 
    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i<pdusObj.length; i++) 
    { 
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu ((byte[]) 
            pdusObj[i]); 
            sender = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
    }
```

Comment: You can use as 'public static String sender'.So from other class you can access it directly.Your sender is containing the last message address.you can also save it to preference so you can access it

Comment: thanks, are there any options besides making it static? i've tried using set and getter methods but still displaying null value

Comment: Without static if you want to access sender using getter, you have to create an instance that is different copy of sender.So you won't get the string you need

Comment: oh, that's why. thank you very much